# Delete from one table unless row is referenced in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have two tables, that look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE devices(
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "last_log_id" integer NULL
);

CREATE TABLE log(
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    "created_at" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "msg" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
);

ALTER TABLE "devices" ADD CONSTRAINT 
   "device_last_log_id" FOREIGN KEY ("last_log_id") 
   REFERENCES "log" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

What is an efficient query to delete all "log" rows older than a certain "created_at" date, unless they are referenced by the "devices" table "last_log_id" column?

Comment: `delete from log l where ceated_at < 'somedate' and not exists (select 1 from devices d where d.device_last_log_id = l.id);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete from log l
where l.created_at < 'somedate'
and not exists (select 1
     from devices d
     where d.last_log_id = l.id
    );
```